# lemmatizing verbs in SVOs

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, space, lemmatization

*I've looked at the suggested similar questions, and I think that this question has enough specificity that it warrants being asked, but I am completely okay if someone can point to an already answered question that solves my problem.*

I have a corpus of texts which I have rendered as (textacy) SVOs, and then saved to a data frame, only to discover that it would be better if the verbs in question were lemmatized so that "talk", "talked", "was talking", "is talking", etc. are rendered as the same verb and not 4 or more different verbs.

The current code grabs the texts out of a data frame and places them in a list:

```py
texts_women = talks_f.text.tolist()
texts_w = [text.lower() for text in texts_women]
```

Then it creates a spaCy pipe and runs the texts through it:

```py
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
docs_w = list(nlp.pipe(texts_w))
```

I had written the following code before realizing that the verbs could use being normalized:

```py
def createSVOs(doc, svo_list):
    # Create the list of tuples for the document
    svotriples = list(textacy.extract.triples.subject_verb_object_triples(doc))
    # Convert to list of dictionaries
    for item in svotriples:
        svo_list.append(
            {
                'subject': item[0][-1], 
                'verb': item[1][-1], 
                'object': item[2]
            }
        )
```

Originally we had converted the dictionary values to strings -- `'subject': str(item[0][-1]) -- and then this list of dictionaries was converted to a pandas dataframe, where we do a number of other things.

Backtracking into the code, I first tried lemmatizing the df['verb'] column, with a variety of errors depending on what I tried, with most of them being:

```py
TypeError: 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' object is not subscriptable
```

I eventually decided to try to lemmatize the docs before I fed them into the textacy SVO creator, but then I get:

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sents'
```

Is it possible to get both SVOs and lemmas? That is, an SVO where the V, verb, is lemmatized? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The working answer to this problem, for now, is to lemmatize the verbs after they have been compiled into the data frame. That answer by [Matias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5951112/matias) is found here: [lemmatizing a verb list in a data frame in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394840/lemmatizing-a-verb-list-in-a-data-frame-in-python). If anyone coming across this question later has an answer to the question of getting a lemmatized verb out of a spaCy/textacy SVO triplet, I would surely like to know it.